# changing background color depending on parent page

Tags: page-template

Hopefully it will be an easy question.

I created Wordpress template and now i would like to use that template for for several pages, however i would like to have different background color on some of the elements such as footer, header etc. that will be depending on parent. So lets say i have PARENT A (green background) and PARENT B (white background) now when i will create child of PARENT A i would like it to have green background automatically I know something similar could be done with posts using

`<div class="post <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) { echo $cat->cat_name . ' '; } ?>"> </div>`

I need some advice what would be the best way to do that.

I hope it makes sense, sorry if i made it confusing.

Many thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing background color depending on parent page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/changing-background-color-depending-on-parent-page)

Answer (score 2):

Using `body_class()`, by default, WordPress adds classes like `parent-pageid-43` to it. This only goes one level deep, though.

The code below works for any ancestors of your parent pages, not just children. It relies on the [is_page_or_ancestor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/is-page-or-ancestor/) for that.

As kaiser said, body classes are the way to go. You can define the name of the classes for each template yourself by modifying the `$parents` array.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_class', 10, 2);

function my_body_class($wp_classes, $extra_classes)
{
    // List of parent pages with custom template
    $parents = array(
        // page ID => body class
        43 => 'template-a',
        57 => 'template-b',
    );

    // Loop over each parent
    foreach ($parents as $page_id => $class)
    {
        // http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/is-page-or-ancestor/
        if (is_page_or_ancestor($page_id))
        {
            // Add body class
            $wp_classes[] = $class;
        }
    }

    // Add the extra classes back untouched
    return array_merge($wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `$post->post_parent` having the global `$post` inside your loop, based on that you could pick your background color.

Answer (score 0):

Easy via css if you use the `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` function in your templates. This would give you a class of `.page-child` on child-pages that can be easily styled. Simply copy your styles and prefix the definitions with `.page-child`. Then re-style them.