# Changing background color depending on parent page?

Tags: theme-development

I created a WordPress template and now I would like to use that template for several pages, however I would like to have different background color on some of the elements such as footer, header etc... which will depend on the parent.

So lets say I have PARENT A (green background) and PARENT B (white background) now when I will create child of PARENT A I would like it to have green background automatically. I know something similar could be done with posts using

```
<div class="post <?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
echo $cat->cat_name . ' ';
} ?>">
</div>
```

I need some advice what would be the best way to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minor css-change based on topmenu - how?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/minor-css-change-based-on-topmenu-how)

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is using the `body_class();` function then you can target pages via CSS.

If you have parent page with the ID of 2 and the background you wanted to change was the .content div, you would simply use :

`.parent-pageid-2 .content {
   background: green;
}`

Or something similar to that effect. This would work for as many child pages you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of the code below, having a different div depending on the page id. Put the style in your CSS obviously, but this paints the picture. Put the code in whatever php file you're applying this to.

```
<?php if (is_page('30')) { ?>
    <div id="page30" style="background:blue;">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="default" style="background:white;">
<?php } ?>
<!-- content inside div -->
</div>
```

Comment: but will only work for single pages and every time i will create new page i will need to go to source code and change it also, but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To add to what TomHarrigan wrote you can try something like post_parent, ... I'll assume you mean page parents.

```
$children = get_children( "post_type=page&post_parent=PARENT_A" );

if $children { 
<div id="page30" style="background:blue;">
}
```

You should have a look into using the Options API for this type of stuff.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API